# xcode c/c++ linker error: undefined symbol

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, debugging

I did some search but my problem seems to be trivial so that no one asked.
I have a mixed c and c++ code.

In `model.h`, I have the following declaration:

```
void free_and_null (char **ptr);
```

In `model.cpp`, I have the function body:

```
void free_and_null (char **ptr)
{
    if ( *ptr != NULL ) {
        free (*ptr);
        *ptr = NULL;
    }
} /* END free_and_null */
```

In a `solve.c` file, I have the following :

```
#include "sort.h"
.....
    free_and_null ((char **) &x);
```

When I compile the project, it has the following linker error:

> wrap)
>   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_free_and_null", referenced from:

Why such a simple program can have error? I use Apple LLVM 6.0 as the compiler. Any input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You need to tell the C++ compiler that the function should have "C" linkage by declaring it as such (in your C++ source file).

```
extern "C" {
  void free_and_null (char **ptr);
}
```

C++ compilers construct "mangled" names for functions so that two functions with the same name but different argument types end up having different mangled names; that's necessary because linkers expect all names to be unique. Consequently, the code generated by the C++ compiler in your example will produce a different name than the name produced by the C compiler. (On Intel platforms, C compilers also modify names slightly, by prefixing an underscore, which is why it complains that `_free_and_null` is unfound.)

One common way of doing this is to make a header file which uses preprocessor macros to detect the language. It's not fully portable, but it should work in your case:

```
// File model.h
// This will not work with all C++ compilers, but it works with clang and gcc
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void free_and_null (char **ptr);
// Other function declarations here

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you rici!  It works! It brought up my faded memory about compiler and linker. But I still can't remember, in Xcode, .c files and .c++ files are compiled with different compiler? 

I'm new to Xcode. I used to use MS Visual studio, which is amazingly convenient and helpful. But I since I like Macbook, I have moved all application softwares to mac os version. Xcode seems not as convenient as MS Visual studio. Could you recommend some IDE for C/C++ coding on mac os? Thanks!

Comment: @user43964: It's the same compiler suite (clang) but name mangling is part of the ABI and that requires C and C++ names to be handled differently. I don't know much about windows but it would surprise me if it were different. Perhaps your Windows IDE didnt let you mix languages in a project. If you compile the C code with c++ it will usually work ok, and you have no naming issues. As far as mac os x goes, the only IDE I've used is xcode.